# Most efficient way to melt dataframe with a ton of possible values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long format dataframe like the following:

[image]

In reality, my dataframe is about 10k rows and there are about 400 possible values of category.  I'd like to melt my dataframe into a wide format like the following:

[image]

I can think of a couple ways to do this, but what would be an efficient way to do this transformation?

Comment: Kindly share data not pics. The solutions proffered are great; however pandas crosstab is quite slow compared to groupby; you may have to do some work to get better speeds;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `crosstab`

```
 out = pd.crosstab(df['Obs'], df['Category'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Obs'], df['Category'])
```